# Is there a special bracha or prayer that one can say when receiving a life-changing implant?

Tags: blessing, handicap-disabled-impair

A deaf person cannot fulfill mitzvoth that specifically require hearing, such as Shofar.

If that person receives a cochlear implant so that he can now hear, other than, most likely saying "Hatov Vehamaitiv", is there some other appropriate blessing or prayer that he can or should say now that he is able to perform mitzvoth that he was never able to perform before?

If he does say a blessing should it be said immediately after receiving the implant as a means of appreciating the mere ability to perform the new mitzvoth, or should he say it immediately preceding or following the actual performance of the 1st "new" mitzvah?

The above is an example. You can apply the same idea to a blind person's receiving a new eye, and numerous other similar examples.

Comment: Why do you suspect there is any special prayer for this, beyond a possible "generic" Shehchiyanu/HaTov...?

Comment: Shehecheyanu, probably. But we say Shehecheyanu when hearing the shofar anyways...

Comment: @LN6595, but the question is about saying the prayer when receiving the implant, not when hearing the _shofar_.

Comment: @msh210 if that's the question...Baruch rofeh cholim, then. We usually leave out shem umalchus.

Comment: @LN6595, if you can support that, then I encourage you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @LN6595 I'm using Shofar as an example. Cochlear implants are also an example. You can apply it to someone who had no arms or hands. Now he has artificial limbs so he can hold a lulav and etrog. The question is general. If you can support your proposed answer, it works!

Comment: @LN6595 I got it. I'll edit.

Comment: @DanF You don't need hands to hold a lulav

Comment: @LN6595 That isn't a special prayer for this circumstance, but for any time one recovers from illness. Nothing to do with ability to perform new mitzvot.

Comment: This sounds like something to make a seudas hoda'a when it is determined that it now works rather than a specific bracha. There is a Yehi Ratzon to say asking Hashem to cause the refuah to work, but that is before taking the medicine or undergoing the procedure.

Comment: There is an argument if one says a Brocho (shehecheyanu) on reaching seventy.

Comment: @DanF would someone be yotze lulav and esrog if he's holding it with fake hands? And I don't know how a cochlear implant works, but I'm not sure it's so different to hearing it through a microphone in which case he's not yotze.

Comment: @user613 You really don't know how a cochlear implant works, or know that, in fact, there is a well researched article regarding the halachic implications of using hearing aids and implants. In some ways, implants are less of a halachic problem regarding hearing than aids are. I'll see if I can find the link to this article. You've made a wrong assumption.

Comment: @user613 I cannot locate an online link to the guide called "Torat Hacheresh" published by Rav Mordechai Shuchatowitz, one of the heads of the Baltimore Va'ad. Extremely well reserahced article. If interested, you can email mshuch@iname.com. The guide is also available via the OU.